# Log() behaviour and number# notation

Tags: vba, type-conversion

Below example from Excel Help about VBA `Log` function, notation `number#` makes conversion of `number`into decimal data type, but makes it any difference for `Log` function if it takes `10` instead of `10#` as an argument ?

```
Static Function Log10(X)

    Log10 = Log(X) / Log(10#)

End Function
```

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference I think.  You could instead use `Application.Log10()` (the worksheet function)

Answer (score 1):

To explain why it won't make a difference I need to explain how type conversion is handled in VBA.

In VBA, by default types are attempted to be **implicitly** converted to the type required by a function/operation, using the default conversions based on your system locale (the system locale bit has meaning when it comes to dates and converting numbers as strings to a numeric type and vice versa).

Consider:

```
Dim aNumber As Integer, aString As String
aString = 1 & 2
aNumber = aString
aNumber = aString + 1
MsgBox aNumber
```

In the above, the numbers 1 and 2 are implicitly converted to strings. As system locale doesn't matter when dealing with integral types, aString subsequently is storing "12". Assigning a string to a number results in the string being implicitly converted to a number, so aNumber subsequently is 12, then 13 after the addition. Calling MsgBox passing in a number will result in the number being converted to a string **before** it is passed in.

Implicit type conversion like the above cannot be disabled in VBA, unlike in VB that has the `Option Strict` directive.

**So, for your Log question above, an integral type passed in will be implicitly converted to a double before actually being passed in.** Passing in e.g. `10#` compared to `10` will save the conversion (an utterly irrelevant performance consideration) but otherwise is semantically equivalent.